# Margin: auto doesn't work if display is box in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, flexbox

In Firefox (version 8.0), if I specify an element to be `display: -moz-box` and `margin: auto`, the element is no longer placed at the center of its parent element. It works in Chrome. Is this a problem of Firefox, or am I missing anything? How can I solve this problem?

One workaround can be adding a wrapper `div` element and setting its `display` as `block`, but this is ugly.

Comment: Can we see all of your code? I can't reproduce this problem in Firefox.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`-moz-box` is the display type for XUL boxes in Firefox.  They don't follow a normal CSS box model, so don't auto-center when you use auto margins.  So the behavior here is correct in Firefox as far as it goes: that's just the behavior of XUL boxes.

Note that `-webkit-box` (which I assume is what you meant by "works in Chrome") is a totally different thing: it's an implementation of one of the very early CSS flexbox drafts.  It shares some superficial features with `-moz-box` and for that matter with the current flexbox drafts, but is otherwise completely different.

Now the real question is... what are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, @BorisZbarsky! So I have a `<hgroup>` I want to put at the center of `<header>` and two block elements I want to put horizontally at the center of `<hgroup>`. I think I can do it in other ways too, like using `inline-block`.

Comment: Yeah, `inline-block` sounds like the way to go there.  It'd have the additional benefit of working in IE and Opera, not just Gecko and WebKit.

Comment: Is `-webkit-box` a totally different thing? According to MDN, [Firefox supports Flexbox 2009](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Flexbox#Compatibility). The real reason `margin:auto` doesn't work in Firefox is that Firefox treats all flexboxes as inline flexboxes.

Comment: Ignore my comment. From the bug report, it's pretty clear that you're much more qualified to talk about this issue than I am. :P

Answer (score 2):

I created a minimal example and tested it under Firefox 7.0.1 unde ubuntu:

```
<div style="border:1px solid blue;width:200px;height:200px;float:left">
<div style="display:block; margin:auto;width:100px;height:50px;">display: block</div>
</div>

<div style="border:1px solid blue;width:200px;height:200px;float:left">
<div style="display:-moz-box; margin:auto;width:100px;height:50px;">display: -moz-box</div>
</div>
```

Result is below. Hope this information helps you.[image]

Comment: Thanks, @Simon! This illustrates the problem very well.

Answer (score 1):

[According to the official W3C spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/#auto-margins) `margin: auto;` should affect `flex` elements in the same way as it affects `block` elements. Firefox's implementation is an early one that is not currently inline with the spec. I have been informed that a fresh implementation will land around version 18.

Comment: The chunk of spec you referenced is actually about the effects of `margin:auto` on things _within_ an element with `display:flex` -- it says nothing about how it behaves on `display:flex` element itself.  So I don't think that chunk of spec is relevant to this question.  (Also, this question is about `-moz-box`, not `flex` -- as Boris indicated in his answer, those two layout models are at best distant relatives, and they shouldn't generally be expected to have the same behavior.)